# xpath for right arrow on instagram profile posts view not working for all posts(python, selenium, chromedriver)

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I am trying to click on right arrow on instagram profile to go through all posts.

This is my current code that navigates to first post and clicks on the right arrow to go to the second post:

```
 driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/")
time.sleep(2)
#click on first post
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//div[contains(@class,'_2z6nI')]//div//div//div[1]//div[1]//a[1]//div[1]//div[2]"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
#hit next
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

When I try to click on the arrow using the same xpath to go to the third post it does not work because the xpath for the arrow has changed. I would appreciate any help on how to solve this problem. I would like to keep pressing the arrow while posts exist.
For reference: 1. I first navigate to https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/ 2. Finding and clicking on the first post results in https://www.instagram.com/p/B-KvtQbil7m/ 3. Clicking on the arrow once results in https://www.instagram.com/p/B9t8tu4KeYK/ If I try the same

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a').click()
```

again I am not able to go to the third post. How can I select a generic xpath that wil work for the right click arrow after every post? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.find_element_by_css_selector`.

The `Next` button on Instagram you mean using this selector on all pages:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow').click()
```

Comment: Thank you. Any advice on how to point to elements whose xpaths seem to be randomly generated when page is refreshed? For instance, I am trying to point to the post (image and comments block) when clicking through a user's posts. I tried finding similar selectors and xpaths but couldn't find any.

Comment: @AD Your question is too broad, can you explain in more detail? and what the issue you're facing?

Comment: @AD Please create new question for it.

Comment: Yes thank you for your response. For instance, when on this page: (https://www.instagram.com/zuck/) and after clicking on the first post, I am trying to driver.find_element the image w/comments block so that I can eventually take a screenshot of the block. The xpath I see is (//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[1]) and the div class begins with _97aPb, however, when I refresh or go to a different user these change. So, i'm looking for an alternative way to find that element. I want to be able to click to the next post and be able to find the (post +comment) for all posts.

Comment: Making a question.

Comment: @AD If this answer useful, please hit upvote `^` button, for future reader, feel free :)